# How to get get string between two wildcards?

Tags: azure, substring, wildcard, azure-data-factory

In adf, i want to pass file type with wildcards as a parameter. It should pick up similiar type files from source folder and copy into corresponding folder(created based on file type) in the target.

For example

I am passing *xyz00r37* as a parameter with wildcard char *.To copy the file to target folder xyz00r37,need to get the string between wildcard *.This is my requirement.

In future, filetype name and length may vary.To copy the files dynamically regardless of file type, need to extract the string between * symbol.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure Data Factory expression language functions to get rid of the "*" wildcard.

Here's a sample code where I split the input parameter (input=xyz00r37*) and got rid of the wildcard.

@split(pipeline().parameters.input, '*')[0]

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways this can achieved . You have not shared the exact file format so few guess .

*wildcard***xyz00r37***wildcard* - @replace(pipeline().parameters.filename,'*','')

*wildcard***xyz00r37***wildcard* - @split(pipeline().parameters.filename,'*')[1]

*wildcard***xyz00r37** - @split(pipeline().parameters.filename, '*')[1]

**xyz00r37***wildcard* - @split(pipeline().parameters.filename, '*')[0] ( as called out before ) .

I think replace option takes care of all the scenarios .

HTH